# <c:out> value attribute not displaying

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

My JSP (source below) isn't displaying the `value` attribute of the `<c:out>` tag. Based on the code below, my `${param.username}` is being evaluated correctly. The JSP page is accessed with a request parameter of `?username=jeff`.

Any thoughts on why? I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

JSP, output, and source after translation/compilation below:

**prac.jsp**

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <head><title>Practice JSP</title></head>
    <body>
        <h2>Practice JSP</h2>
        Username: <c:out value="${param.username}" default="No username"/><br/>
    </body>   
</html>
```

**Output**

```
Practice JSP
Username:
```

**Source (right click, view page source from browser)**

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <head><title>Practice JSP</title></head>
    <body>
        <h2>Practice JSP</h2>
        Username: <c:out value="jeff" default="No username"/><br/>
    </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here,

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

you're declaring the taglib as a XML namespace which works only in JSPX, not in "plain vanilla" JSP. Since you didn't explicitly mention "JSPX" anywhere in the question, even not in the file extension, I gather that you're actually using "plain vanilla" JSP. In that case, a XML namespace isn't going to work. You need to declare the taglib by `<%@taglib%>`.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
```

Note that I removed the `xmlns:jsp` without a `@taglib` equivalent, as that's already implicitly done by the JSP parser. On contrary to the XML namespace, you don't need to specify the taglib on your own for `http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page`.

Or, if you actually intend to use JSPX, then you should be renaming the file to `prac.jspx`.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I could have sworn that I that `xmlns:` worked in both JSP and JSPX - I guess it's not the case.

Comment: JSP is not XML based. JSPX is XML based. JSP's successor Facelets is also XML based.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

this will make jstl tags available to your jsp and solve your problem.